# Unity Like Desktop Environment

Tags: 16.04, unity, software-recommendation, desktop-environments

Now that Unity is no longer going to stay forever, which is the Desktop Environment that can be **most easily tweaked** to give a **very close Unity Like Experience?**

I am looking for features such as

- One beautiful left Launcher(gives good amount of usable screen estate)
- Left Window Buttons(minimises waste mouse movement all over the screen when combined with Left Launcher)
- Top panel for all system info and indicator stuff
- Minimalist and modern design

Hope I find something like this before Unity is completely gone.

Answer (score 2):

MATE has a built in theme called Mutiny that's almost exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: You might be able to improve this answer with providing the steps needed to get this theme and install it in more detail and maybe even adding screen-shots of different parts to make it a rock solid answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! Works almost perfect except for the quick search dash option. If there is no better way, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: It even allows setting Compiz as window manager. But probably this will be gone once Compiz dies along with Unity. Am I right?